# twisted.reactor callWhenRunning and callLater undefined?

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I am working with twisted and...well these two methods keep coming up in Eclipse as undefined. Cannot find any reference to this.

I tried #@UndefinedVariable (which solved the reactor.run() issue I had but it does not work in this case.

Running Eclipse Kepler on Mac Yosemite with twisted-15.2.1 zope.interface-4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Python data structures can change at runtime, so Eclipse can only guess what methods are available.  In the case of `twisted.internet.reactor`, it is a singleton whose type may change depending on how things are initialized, so it appears to Eclipse as a blank module.

Since PyDev for Eclipse does not provide a way for libraries to tell it that it's wrong about what methods it has detected, if your Python code does not match the subset of Python it can guess correctly about, then you get spurious errors like this.  Sorry!  If PyDev ever adds a way to override its built-in guessing logic, we will distribute something that says what methods `twisted.internet.reactor` likely provides.  Please file a bug against PyDev for this.